# Windows Server 2019 Hyper-V guest simultaneous access

Tags: hyper-v, ntfs, windows-server-2019

Environment is a standalone Windows Server 2019 hosting multiple Hyper-V machines running on it.
The idea was to be able to mount a single specific virtual disks to multiple virtual machines and be able to simultaneously read and write to it from all guests. Basically similar to a network share but based on virtual disks.
After many unsuscessful attempts and even trying to setup iSCSI, Failover Clustering and SOFS I had to realise that it will not work as intended.

So here is the question: Is it even possible to have multiple Windows 10 guests having the same (data) vm disk mounted and write and read simultaneously to it? 
I have read now that NtFs is the culprit which would not allow it.
If so, are there ways in the meantime? Does other file system support it (ReFs maybe?) is there additional software that I could use to circumvent the limitation?
I don't want to use network shares for this specific case, I know it could be done via network.

So if you have any ideas or experience, I kindly ask to share.

Comment: Disk access brokering doesn't work that way. Why not just make another VM that's a file server?

Comment: @EricSiron Thanks for confirming this. I just thought it could be possible as 
 everything gets more and more virtualized I was hoping disk access brokering would offer new options now. Basicyally the technology seems to be in place with failover clustering or SMB3 but not in the way I would like to have it.

Answer (score 4):

You need clustered filesystem to solve your task. Microsoft has Shared VHDX functionality, however, it requires CSV (Clustered Shared Volume) underneath. https://www.vembu.com/blog/shared-vhdx-vhd-sets-windows-server-2016-hyper-v/
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/vhd-set-feature-in-microsoft-windows-server-2016/
You can do a nested Failover Cluster and create CSV there. In my opinion, it is to complicated for a single host. Create a separate VM and deploy File Server there.